# List blob from Azure Blob Storage and Readstream in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

here is my code how I list the blobs.

EDITED!!!

------------------------------------EDIT------------------------------------------

I edited the code and rewrite in this TypeScript:

```
    const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(`https://${accountName}.blob.core.windows.net?${sasToken}`,
      pipeline)
    const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName)
    console.log(containerClient)
    if (!containerClient.exists()) {
      console.log("the container does not exit")
      await containerClient.create()

    }
    const client = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(this.currentFile.name)

    //name of uploded blob
    console.log(this.currentFile.name)
    //metaata from the blob
    console.log(client)

    //List each blobs in the container
    for await (const blob of containerClient.listBlobsFlat()) {
      console.log('\t', blob.name);
      const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blob.name);
      const downloadBlockBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.download(0);
      console.log('\nDownloaded blob content...');
      console.log('\t', await streamToString(downloadBlockBlobResponse.readableStreamBody));
      //end of loop
  }



  async function streamToString(readableStream) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const chunks = [];
      readableStream.on("data", (data) => {
        chunks.push(data.toString());
      });
      readableStream.on("end", () => {
        resolve(chunks.join(""));
      });
      readableStream.on("error", reject);
    });
  }
```

But then I receive an error in the browser which called:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property
> 'on' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined

Comment: Try using `blobServiceClient.downloadToBuffer()` for smaller files(upto 1Gb for 32bit system). 
For larger files try `blobServiceClient.downloadToFile()`.
Refer [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blockblobclient?view=azure-node-latest#downloadtobuffer-number--number--blobdownloadtobufferoptions-) for parameter information

Comment: Still the error: Error running sample: blobServiceClient.downloadFile is not a function

Comment: My bad, pls try 
<code> for await (const blob of blobs) {
   console.log(\`Blob ${i++}: ${blob.name}\`);
   const blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(blob.name);
   var stream = blobClient.downloadToBuffer();
   // stream.pipe(res)
  }
 </code>

Comment: Thanks Hemant. How can I display the contents of var stream? does the "stream" contains the blob contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the blob by calling the `download` method. The example code includes a helper function called `streamToString`, which is used to read a Node.js **readable stream into a string**.

Add this code to the end of the main function:

```
const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blob.name);
const downloadBlockBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.download(0);
console.log('\nDownloaded blob content...');
console.log('\t', await streamToString(downloadBlockBlobResponse.readableStreamBody));
```

Add this helper function after the main function:

```
// A helper function used to read a Node.js readable stream into a string
async function streamToString(readableStream) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const chunks = [];
    readableStream.on("data", (data) => {
      chunks.push(data.toString());
    });
    readableStream.on("end", () => {
      resolve(chunks.join(""));
    });
    readableStream.on("error", reject);
  });
}
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-nodejs#download-blobs).

Comment: I edited it and then I receive another error in TypeScript